# Making a link stay active displaying hover effect upon click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am struggling to make this work.  I'd like to make it where if <kbd>O.F.</kbd> is clicked, the hover state stays active, if another link is clicked, for example, Founders, the hover state that was active on <kbd>O.F.</kbd> disappears and the hover state stays active on Founders.  Where am I going wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="profile_list">
     <h2>Members: 37</h2>
 <a href="#Original_Founder" class="panel">• O.F.</a>
 <a href="#Founder" class="panel">• Founder</a>
 <a href="#Leader" class="panel">• Leader</a>
 <a href="#Senior_Admin" class="panel">• Sr. Admin</a>
 <a href="#Junior_Admin" class="panel">• Jr. Admin</a>
 <a href="#Full_Member" class="panel">• Full-Member</a>
 <a href="#Greenhorn" class="panel">• Greenhorn</a>
 <a href="#Inactive" class="panel">• Inactive</a>
 <a href="#Legend" class="panel">• Legend</a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#profile_list {
    width: 250px;
    height: 328px;
    background-color: #333;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#777), to(#222));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#profile_list h2 {
    width: 226px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    float: left;
    color: #B45F04;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
}
#profile_list a {
    width: 218px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 12px 7px 20px;
    color: #A4A4A4;
    float: left;
    font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
#profile_list a:hover, #profile_list a.active {
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.profile_list').click(function () {
        var a = $(this);
        $(this).addClass('.active');
    });
});
```

Here is a demo of what I have so far, but when I click on any link, the hover state does not stay active: http://jsfiddle.net/WgdXU/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**replace**

```
$(this).addClass('.active');
```

**with**

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

you do not need to add . for addClass

and also **Replace**

```
$('a.profile_list').click(function () {
```

**with**

```
$('#profile_list a').click(function () {
```

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WgdXU/6/)

**Comment Edit**

http://jsfiddle.net/WgdXU/8/

Comment: dude.. he is referring to a wrong A tag which also needs to be corrected. :)

Comment: @GaneshPandhere i know i have added that too,

Comment: This is very close, however, upon clicking on a different link, I'd like for the hover state to be removed, that way only 1 link is active at a time rather than all if you click through them all...

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/WgdXU/7/

**JS:-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#profile_list a').click(function () {
        $('#profile_list a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: this will go on adding class to every element which is not desirable action.

Comment: This is very close, however, upon clicking on a different link, I'd like for the hover state to be removed, that way only 1 link is active at a time rather than all if you click through them all...

Comment: @user2732875 Already handled that situation in the updated code.

Comment: @ user2732875 that is something which I did already. then why my code was downvoted? I got your code wiz kid... :)

Comment: I can't give correct answers to everyone, but I did give you a plus 1 as your method worked perfectly too!  The only reason why I made Dipesh's answer as the correct one because he managed to only use 5 lines as opposed to 6.  Thank you for your help though ;)

Comment: @user2732875 He has removed `document.ready` which is required. The code should be inside `document.ready` event.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on that?  I am currently using what Dipesh provided (without the document.ready) event and it is working perfectly - exactly the same as what you provided - the only difference is that it uses 1 less line...Personally, I too thought I needed the `document.ready` event, but apparently not...

Comment: I do thank you again for helping out though, if anyone see's this question that got stuck like I did, I hope they read both your's and Dipesh's answer as both are correct!

Answer (score 0):

Change your script as below :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a.panel').click(function () {
    var a = $(this); // no need of having this variable as it is not being used. You can remove it.
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "profile_list" is an id use "#profile_list" instead of ".profile_list".
Also for adding the class active you need not use the "."

Please try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#profile_list a').click(function () {
    var a = $(this);
    $('#profile_list a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```

Thanks