# toggling a link's activity on click using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question similar to this question [Making a link stay active displaying hover effect upon click using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911800/making-a-link-stay-active-displaying-hover-effect-upon-click-using-javascript) i just wanted to disable the active class when the link is clicked again any help would be appreciated

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WgdXU/8/)

**HTML**

```
  <div id="profile_list">
     <h2>Members: 37</h2>
     <a href="#Original_Founder" class="panel">• O.F.</a>
     <a href="#Founder" class="panel">• Founder</a>
     <a href="#Leader" class="panel">• Leader</a>
     <a href="#Senior_Admin" class="panel">• Sr. Admin</a>
     <a href="#Junior_Admin" class="panel">• Jr. Admin</a>
     <a href="#Full_Member" class="panel">• Full-Member</a>
     <a href="#Greenhorn" class="panel">• Greenhorn</a>
     <a href="#Inactive" class="panel">• Inactive</a>
     <a href="#Legend" class="panel">• Legend</a>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('#profile_list a').click(function() {
    var a = $(this);
    $('#profile_list a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

**CSS**

```
 #profile_list {
    width: 250px;
    height: 328px;
    background-color: #333;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#777), to(#222));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#777, #222);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
 }
 #profile_list h2 {
    width: 226px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    float: left;
    color: #B45F04;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
 }
 #profile_list a {
    width: 218px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 12px 7px 20px;
    color: #A4A4A4;
    float: left;
    font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
 }
 #profile_list a:hover, #profile_list a.active {
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    color: #FFF;
 }
```

Comment: You must show your effort.

Comment: Can you show the html of the link?  The answer should be something close to `document.getElementById("[ID OF THE <a>]").className = ""` but if you have more than just one class on it, you'll have to remove just that class.

Comment: the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WgdXU/8/

Comment: Don't just post a fiddle, edit your question with the pertinent code.

Comment: i dont know javascript well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then do two checks, one to see if the clicked anchor is active already and another to see if any of that anchors siblings are active.

- If it's already active, "deactive" it by removing the class.
- If one of its siblings is active during the click, don't activate it.
- If neither it nor its siblings are active, activate it.

**JS**

```
// Add a click listener to the anchors of profile_list
$('#profile_list a').click(function () {
    // Set variables for this,
    // Whether I am the active one,
    // And if there are other active elements in this list
    var a = $(this),
        amIactive = a.hasClass('active'),
        areOthersActive = a.parent().children().hasClass('active');

    // If I'm active
    if (amIactive) {
        // Make me not active when I'm clicked
        a.removeClass('active');
    }
    // Otherwise, if none of my siblings are active
    else if(!areOthersActive){
        // Make me active
        a.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Forked fiddle with changes: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zero298/DZN8V/)

Comment: i'm tryin to also ensure only one link can be actve at a time

Comment: @user3005115 Ok, check my edits.  This should make it so that only one is active at a time.  Also, please add that you want only one to be active at a time to your question.